# Python Key/Value point to same random number

Tags: python

I have a function in Python where I need a Key/Value to point to the same random number that is chosen, I can't figure this out and couldn't find any examples on doing this. Does anyone have any suggestions:

```
def generatePhrase():
        print '\n'
        print 'Now Generating Phrase....'
        print 'And Here we go!!!'
        print '\n'
        phrase = {'Created by ATNT in 1970s':'UNIX','Developed by Sun Microsystems':'Java','Worst Operating System in the World':'Windows','Containerizing Environments':'Docker','Built by Python, used for Automation':'Ansible'}
        randomPhrase = random.choice(phrase.keys())
        print randomPhrase + '\n'
        randomValue = random.choice(phrase.values())
        print randomValue.replace(randomValue,"_ " * len(randomValue))
        return randomPhrase
```

So what happens when I run the code is this:

```
Now Generating Phrase....
And Here we go!!!


Created by ATNT in 1970s

_ _ _ _ _ _ _
```

I need the randomValue variable to use the same random number that was generated as randomPhrase. Can someone tell me how to do this?

Comment: I can't see how this was down voted

Comment: Once you randomly chosed the key of your dictionary, you can access the value by accessing your dictionary using that key.

Comment: Yeah i figured that would be the case..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
randomValue = phrase[randomPhrase]
```

This will ensure you'll get corresponding value.

```
import random

phrase = {'Created by ATNT in 1970s':'UNIX','Developed by Sun Microsystems':'Java','Worst Operating System in the World':'Windows','Containerizing Environments':'Docker','Built by Python, used for Automation':'Ansible'}
randomPhrase = random.choice(phrase.keys())
randomValue = phrase[randomPhrase]

print randomPhrase, randomValue

>>> Developed by Sun Microsystems Java
```